# number of months between two dates in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a report in Salesforce that contains an **Estimated Start Date** and **Estimated End Date** - see below example:

[image]

What I want to do is create a formula column that will allow me to show how many months are between those dates.

I can do this easily in excel using DATEDIF but cannot replicate that in the salesforce report itself - see below example of desired result using DATEDIF in excel:

[image]

Can anyone advise on the easiest way to achieve this result as a formula column in Salesforce?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating a field with the below formula

```
((CloseDate - Estimated_Start_Date__c) /(365/12))
```